# Vue-props: can i use type props with $t{{}}

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

This is similar to the code that i have

```
<component
type="example" />
```

but i want to use it like this

```
<component
type="{{ $t('common.forms.search') }}" />
```

problem is that its not working

Comment: Where is $t coming from, and what should it actually do ?

Answer (score 1):

You bind properties in Vue like this:

```
<component :type="$t('common.forms.search')" />
```

or verbose:

```
<component v-bind:type="$t('common.forms.search')" />
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes